# Aws IOT Jobs in Python

Tags: python, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-iot

i have created a job using boto3

```
import boto3 

client = boto3.client('iot')
response = client.create_job(
    jobId='job_id',
    targets=[
        'thing_arn',
    ],
    document="{\"operation\":\"restart\"}",
    description='job created using boto',
    targetSelection='SNAPSHOT'
)
```

And i have created a python program that subscribe to listen the response

```
end_point = 'ur end point'
rootCAPath = 'rootCA Path'
certificatePath = 'certificate Path'
privateKeyPath = 'private Key Path'
clientId = 'myClientID'

#$aws/things/thingname/jobs/notify (or 
#$aws/things/thingname/jobs/notify-next)
#$aws/things/thingname/jobs/get/accepted
#$aws/things/thingname/jobs/get/rejected
#$aws/things/thingname/jobs/jobId/get/accepted
#$aws/things/thingname/jobs/jobId/get/rejected

topic = 'try with above all topics'
myAWSIoTMQTTClient = None
myAWSIoTMQTTClient = AWSIoTMQTTClient(clientId)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(end_point, 8883)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureCredentials(rootCAPath, privateKeyPath, certificatePath)
# Connect and Subscribe
while True:
    myAWSIoTMQTTClient.connect(1000)
    #subscribe multiple topic
    myAWSIoTMQTTClient.subscribe(topic, 1, customCallback)
    time.sleep(2)
```

while i listen to the topic mentioned above there is no any response.I also checked it with aws iot console (TEST) and subscribed the above given topics there also no any response.How the job is send to registered iot device and **on which topic did the job details is send to that device** ?

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never for who is still stumbling on the problem.

Make sure that the `$` is included in the topic. This was what was going wrong for me.

The response comes back on the `/accepted` or `/rejected` (`/#` for the combination of them).

Also you might want to subscribe to the topic `$aws/events/#` to check if your device subscribed to the topic when testing.

[This](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-device-management-workshop/blob/master/AWS_IoT_Device_Management_Workshop.md) example might help you.